# CSS - Change background url when touchscreen zooms in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a touchscreen and on this screen (1920 x 1080) the user has the ability to pan and zoom using their fingers.

On this screen I am displaying a floor plan. which has been a nightmare making them look not blurry when not zoomed in vs zoomed in....Here is my css code and the image looks good not zoomed in

```
.blackline {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 375px;
    height: 850px;
    width: 1058px;
    background: url('/images/floorplans/test-2.png') top center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

<div class="blackline"></div>
```

I have another image called test.png  which looks good when zoomed in on the touchscreen.

My question is would I change the background image either using css, html, javascript or jquery when zooming in and change it back when not zooming in? Is this possible?

Comment: You should consider using an SVG image for the floorplan instead, which should render sharp at any zoom level.

Comment: Yea, I tried that....the floor plans I have are originally 4959 x 4091 in a PDF...on I resize it a smaller size it looks good when not zoomed in and when I convert it svg in its original size, it looks pixelated and blurry on both zoomed in and zoomed out.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to consider and SVG image because is not distorting itself while zooming (you have not to change it even if the zoom is changed).

Another approach is to change the background image according to the zoom level through JQuery:

```
var zoom = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;
$(window).resize(function() {
    var zoomNew = document.documentElement.clientWidth / window.innerWidth;
    if (zoom != zoomNew) {
        // zoom has changed
        // change the background image accordingly
        //and set new zoom as current zoom
        zoom = zoomNew
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the best way to convert a PDF 4959 x 4091 to svg for touchscreen? I tried it in photoshop....the end result looked terrible.

Comment: You can import the PDF into a program called Inkscape. If it's already vector then you just need to export it to SVG. If it's a raster image (PNG, etc.) you can trace the bitmap in Inkscape, delete the bitmap and export the traced vectors as SVG.

Comment: trying inkscape now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If this is the right way of doing what you requested, but you can create a @media to change the background url on screen size.

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
    .background {
        background-image:url(image.nl);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps but this probably isn't the right way of doing things.